# How to calculate probability of success for 2 random events

Tags: probability

For the purposes of simplicity, I am considering 2 variables here:

I will be considering Player to be a person rolling 1dN exploding die, where N can equal 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20. With the help of @peterwhy in my previous post (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4473595/1068076), I was able to come up with the equation $P_1(x,n)=\left \{ (x>0)\wedge (x \textrm{ mod }n>0):\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\left(1+\left \lfloor \left ( \frac{1}{n} \right ) \right \rfloor\right)},0 \right \}$ to calculate the probability of rolling a value $x$ on an $n$-sided exploding die.

I will be considering Dealer to be a person rolling 2d10, both of which can explode. Again, thanks to @peterwhy, the equation $P_2(x,n)=\sum_{i=1}^{x}P_1(i,n)P_1(x-i,n)$ defines the probability of rolling value $x$ on 2 $n$-sided exploding dice. $$$$
I need to calculate the probability of success for 3 different situations involving these variables:

Situation 1 - Success occurs when Player rolls higher than Dealer.

Situation 2 - Success occurs when Player rolls lower than Dealer.

Situation 3 - Success occurs when Player rolls equal to Dealer.

So far, I've been attempting to calculating the probability by using the AND principle ($P(x \textrm{ and } y)=P(x)\cdot P(y) $) using summation equations for $x$ an $y$, but those only gave me the probability of success if the Player rolled that value (but even those didn't work properly because I believe they only calculate the probability of this event occurring). The equations I came up with are as follows:
$$\textrm{Situation 1: }P_>(x)=\sum_{i=x}^{100}P_1(i,n)\cdot\sum_{j=0}^{x-1}P_2(j,10)$$
$$\textrm{Situation 2: }P_<(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{x-1}P_1(i,n)\cdot\sum_{j=x}^{100}P_2(j,10)$$
$$\textrm{Situation 3: }P_=(x)=P_1(x,n)\cdot P_2(x, 10)$$

Does anyone know what I can do to find the probability of success for each die and situation?

Comment: Do you want to find an analytical solution? Since you have a finite number of possible $n$, performing a simulation may be good enough.

Comment: @econbernardo I believe that what I need in this situation is an analytical solution

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1644794/915791

Answer (score 1):

While this is not an analytical solution, a numerical simulation can help. I ran 10 million simulations and these are the results:

```
                   4         6         8         10        12        20
Situation 1  0.050170  0.077708  0.114014  0.156185  0.206081  0.421487
Situation 2  0.928287  0.894013  0.851738  0.803438  0.747417  0.534200
Situation 3  0.021544  0.028279  0.034248  0.040377  0.046502  0.044314
```

[image]

Below is the Python code performing these simulations efficiently with NumPy vectorization:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint

def player(N, iters):
    total =  randint(1, N + 1, iters)
    n_rolls = 1
    explodes = total == n_rolls * N # Iterations where only explosions happened until now
    while ( explodes ).any():
        total = total + np.where(explodes, randint(1, N + 1, len(explodes)), 0) # Substituting in these locations
        n_rolls += 1 # Updates maximum total number of rolls
        explodes = total == n_rolls * N # Updates ongoing explosions
    return total

def dealer(iters):
    return player(10, iters) + player(10, iters)

def simulation(iters):
    res = {}
    for N in (4,6,8,10,12,20):
        res_player = player(N, iters)
        res_dealer = dealer(iters)
        
        situation_1 = np.mean( res_player > res_dealer )
        situation_2 = np.mean( res_player < res_dealer )
        situation_3 = np.mean( res_player == res_dealer )
        res[N] = {'Situation 1': situation_1,
                  'Situation 2': situation_2,
                  'Situation 3': situation_3
                 }
    return res

sim_results = simulation(10000000)
```

### Edit: Code for the graphs

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(sim_results)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.title("Exploding Die")
plt.plot((4,6,8,10,12,20), df.T['Situation 1'], label = 'Situation 1', color = 'blue')
plt.plot((4,6,8,10,12,20), df.T['Situation 2'], label = 'Situation 2', color = 'red')
plt.plot((4,6,8,10,12,20), df.T['Situation 3'], label = 'Situation 3', color = 'green')
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.xlabel('N')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is incredibly useful! Did you use anything other than NumPy to generate the graph?

Comment: I used matplotlib for the graphs. I included the code to generate the graphs in an edit in my answer. Also, in the table one of the columns was labeled `5` instead of `6` for $N=6$.

Comment: Say I wanted to add a probability of each situation occurring (Situation 1 is 1/3, Situation 2 is 1/2, and Situation 3 is 1/6). Would I have to add the weight to the returned values in sim_results, or would I add it somewhere else?

Comment: You could do something like: `res[N] = {'Situation 1': (1.0/3) * situation_1,
                                                               'Situation 2': (1.0/2) * situation_2,
                                                               'Situation 3': (1.0/6) * situation_3
                                              }`
replacing the definition of `res[N]`  inside the `simulation` function.